# How to make quoteless, comma delimited list of IDs work for IN clause within MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the situation: I'm running a query (in MySQL) against a **non-normalized** table. I didn't build it, don't blame me. One column in this table consists of a **comma delimited** list of image_ids.

These image IDs correspond to the `Primary Key` within a second table.

I'm trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` in my **`SQL`**, in order to get the images attached to the content:

```
LEFT JOIN image ON image.id IN (content.imageIDs)
```

This errors as **content.imageIDs** are not wrapped in quotes, instead it's just **12345,67890,** etc.

If I can wrap these individual IDs in quotes, it should work. However, I can't work out how to do that.

```
LEFT JOIN image ON image.id IN (REPLACE(content.imageIDs, ',', '\',\''))
```

This gets me closer, but now I'm missing the opening and closing quotes. I've tried using `CONCAT()` to add these, which results in no error, but no results either.

Comment: Even if you manage to surround them in quotes, it still won't work because `REPLACE()` will ultimately return _one string_, not a comma-separated list of values as far as MySQL is concerned.

Comment: ... so the join's `ON` clause would be looking for matches between `image.id` and a _string_ like `"'12345','23456','09876'"` rather than for the individual values.

Comment: Ah. that's probably why it ain't working then...

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" way to do this in MySQL is:

```
LEFT JOIN image ON find_in_set(image.id, content.imageIDs) > 0
```

A general way that works in MySQL and many other databases is:

```
LEFT JOIN image on content.imageIDs like concat('%,', image, ',%')
```

(although the string concatenation function often differs from database to database).